# Similar Theorems to Hall's Theorem on Bipartite Graphs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

By Hall's Theorem, a bipartite graph $G$ with vertex sets $V_1$ and $V_2$ contains a complete matching from $V_1$ to $V_2$ if and only if it satisfies Hall's condition

$|\{v\in V_2: uv\in E ~\text{for some $u\in V_1$}\}|\ge |S|$

for every subset $S\subset V_1$. Here $E$ denotes the set of edges of $G$.

Hall's theorem seems to prove useful when working with matchings and graph colorings. Are there any similar theorems on matchings of complete bipartite graphs? I am trying to find any existing results that may potentially prove to be helpful with colorings and matchings.

Comment: Not sure about complete bipartite graphs, but Hall's Theorem generalises to arbitrary graphs in two very significant ways - for connectivity via Menger's Theorem, and for matchings via Tutte's Matching Theorem (both can be found on wikipedia).

Comment: This can actually be very useful, but could you give some concrete examples own such instances?

Comment: The theorem on matching in complete bipartite graphs I'd give is "$K_{m,n}$ has a perfect matching if and only if $m=n$" and this seems silly, so could you elaborate a bit on what you want that's *not* this?